# Select JavaScript object from onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a parent component that contains two arrays

```
newChoiceArray: [
    { id: 1, text: '1', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '1' },
    { id: 2, text: '2', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '2' },
    { id: 3, text: '3', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '3' },
  ],
  ChoiceArray: [
    { id: 4, text: 'red', questionId: 'favourite colour?', value: '1' },
    { id: 5, text: 'blue', questionId: 'favourite colour?', value: '4' },
  ],
}
```

I have a component that renders a button for each object inside of an array

```
const MultiChoiceQuestions = props => {
  const { multiChoiceArray, handleClick } = props
  return (
    <div>
      {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
        return (
          <button type="button" key={questionChoice.id} onClick={handleClick}>
            {questionChoice.text}
          </button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I render my child component, I can pass an array as a prop

```
<MultiChoiceQuestions handleClick={this.testClick} multiChoiceArray={newChoiceArray} />
<MultiChoiceQuestions handleClick={this.testClick} multiChoiceArray={ChoiceArray} />
```

When I click the button, I want to see which object inside of that array is being selected.

```
    testClick = event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log(event.currentTarget)
  }
```

Instead of outputting this `<button type="button">3</button>`
It should output this `{ id: 3, text: '3', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '3' },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass the object as button value, for example:

```js
{multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
  return (
    <button type="button" key={questionChoice.id} value={JSON.stringify(questionChoice)} onClick={handleClick}>
      {questionChoice.text}
    </button>
  )
}
```

and then you can catch this, using property `value` from currentTarget:

```js
 testClick = event => {
   event.preventDefault()
   console.log(JSON.parse(event.currentTarget.value))
}
```

I don't know if is the best approach, but I know that works.

**UPDATE**

I was wondering about this question, will you use something else from event object ? else you can pass directly the item into the function:

```js
{multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
  return (
    <button type="button" key={questionChoice.id} onClick={() => handleClick(questionChoice)}>
      {questionChoice.text}
    </button>
  )
}


// parent file
testClick = obj => {
   console.log(obj)
}
```

Comment: output is [object Object], is there a way to output the object's props?

Comment: oh ok, I forgot, you pass the object like that: value={JSON.stringfy(questionChoice)}

and then you can use:
JSON.parse(event.currentTarget.value)

Comment: I'm getting an error: TypeError: JSON.stringfy is not a function

Comment: try the second option I just updated, I guess is the best approach to this case, or you can fix TypeError, I wrote wrong... `JSON.stringify(questionChoice)`